# Using dataSet to create XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable, dataset

I already file xml like this

```
<DocumentElement>   
    <Father>
       <Child>
          <Name>Leaf</Name>
       </Child>
       <Mother>
          <Name>Lin</Name>
       </Mother>   
    </Father>  
</DocumentElement>
```

How can I add more Father tags by using DataSet and DataTable in C# and write to xml ?

Result :

```js
    <DocumentElement>   
        <Father>
           <Child>
              <Name>Leaf</Name>
           </Child>
           <Mother>
              <Name>Lin</Name>
           </Mother>  
           <Daughter>
              <Name>Lan</Name>
           </Daughter>
        </Father>  
    </DocumentElement>
```

Comment: I think some information is missing here...

Comment: Excuse me, what's information ? Please tell me

Comment: Well, the question has been kindly edited since I commented with example XML. However, the remaining missing information, is what have you tried so far?

Comment: I try to read this file xml and then write more tag Father like this

Comment: I try to create DataSet with 2 DataTable, then add Column, add Row, and add 2 DataTable in DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

When reading this xml the dataset interprets this as a dataset named "DocumentElemement" with 3 Tables "Father", "Mother", "Child"

Note i have no c# dev environment available and i last used c# 3 years ago so i cannot give you the exact c# code just pseudocode.

You can add more fathers to the dataset if you navigate dataset->Tables("Father")->addRow()

```
dataset.Tables["Father"].Rows.Add(....)
```

The xml can be written back to file with `dataSet.WriteXML(..)` but only in datasets internal xml format that will probably look different than yours. For details see [C# DataSet XML loading and saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300151/c-sharp-dataset-xml-loading-and-saving)